# ion-list not completely shown using virtualScroll ionic2

Tags: angular, cordova, http, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am displaying a list with each row contains image and text. Image for each row will be downloaded from server using REST service. When I click on drop down arrow, it has to display details for each row. But, details for each row are getting overlapped and not completely shown. Code snippet:

```
<ion-list no-lines scrollY="true" [virtualScroll]="allDataArray">
   <ion-item *virtualItem="let item; let i=index" text-wrap>
      <ion-row>
         <ion-row responsive-sm>
            <ion-img src="data:image/*;base64,{{item.imagePhoto}}"></ion-img>
         </ion-row>
         <ion-row *ngIf="isGroupShown(i)">
            <label>{{item.name}}</label>
         </ion-row>
      </ion-row>
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Please let me know where is the problem.
With [virtualScroll] list, it gives a problem.

Thanks,

Comment: can you show a screen shot or better to reproduce using https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: you have ion-row inside another ion-row. check ion-grid documentation for the order of tags

Comment: Hard to reproduce since we cannot get your images from your server.